# Entity Framework : cannot get data right after insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, crud

We have a very standard ASP.NET Core 6 Web API server doing CRUD functions. It is communicating with a SQL Server database using Entity Framework.

The client of the API server tries to retrieve the record (http Get) after creating it (after receiving http ok from Web API create function). However there is nothing returned. We have to wait for a second then the pre-created account can be retrieved.

Client code is not using async call. There is no transaction used either. Database is a SQL Server Express instance on AWS.

How to solve this issue elegantly?

Code example:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly CryptonowContext c;

    public AccountController(CryptonowContext context)
    {
        c = context;
    }

    // Step 1: Create a new account
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Account account)
    {
        context.Accounts.Add(account);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(account);
    }
    
    // Step 2: If we call get api right after create, 
    // the newly created data in step 1 is not found by UUID. 
    // We have to wait a second, then it can be found
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{uuid}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string uuid)
    {
        Account account = context.Accounts.Where(u => u.UUID == uuid).FirstOrDefault();
        return Ok(account);
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string UUID {get; set;}
}
```

What we tried: after inserting the new data, wait a second to retrieve it.

What we want: no waiting.

Comment: Please post some code. Ideally a [mre]. Do you have some db replication going on? _"We found that it fails"_ - please specify how exactly it fails.

Comment: Is the insert being run in a transaction? I saw a program once that started a transaction and auto committed it every X seconds which meant that sometimes you would have to wait X seconds to query the database

Comment: Please clarify. Is it when you call the API get right after the API post that you face the issue ? Or inside one API endpoint you do a dbContect.entity.Add(xxx); and then get it back immediately ? Do you you Save in between ? How do you deal with async ?

Comment: The issue is probably in code you haven't included: I'd guess either the `AccountAction.Add` is doing something asynchronous but isn't waiting for it, or the code consuming this isn't waiting for the asynchronous Create http call to complete before starting the call to Get.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to using different connections when creating and selecting a new record. It is possible that an implicit transaction is used during creation, which is not closed for a while, or is closed when the connection is closed.

Comment: Code is updated. No async call is used

Comment: @Vincent what does the `.Add()` method do ? We need more code details. Also, use `.Equals()` when comparing strings.